# A story about a man who pissed off gods and passes his task on through generations

Tags: story-identification

I don’t remember most of this story. I just remember that this man from possibly a primitive tribe angered the crazy gods and had to run for his life with perhaps a mission. He keeps running, but he is at some point defeated. But not before he passes on his mission to another person. This happens a few times in the book until the last person creates so many people that all fight together and cannot be defeated by mad gods. I found it very touching. I think one of the gods was Bolob. There were multiple gods. I think they reversed their names at a point, but this god’s name remained the same because he was god of gold or something and the greed for gold never changes. It is possible this book was Croatian or from that area. It is a children’s fantasy book. I liked the fight for freedom and transmission of (good) idea

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!